# React router v6 useNavigate does not work after redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

In my React

app, I am trying to navigate to a new page after I dispatch a redux action.

The useNavigate hook definition:

const navigate = useNavigate();

```
const handleEmailsent = async() => {
 await dispatch(sendEmail(email)); //if removed, navigate works. 
navigate("/login"); //does not navigate with the previous line.

};
```

```
const handleEmailsent = async() => {
navigate("/login"); // works before the action 
await dispatch(sendEmail(email));

};
```

How can I make the navigate work after the action is dispatched?

Comment: Please [edit] to include all relevant code you are working with as part of a complete [mcve]. We can't address issues in code we can't see.  Please also clarify what specifically isn't working. If there are any errors in the console, include the complete error message(s) and any accompanying error stacktrace(s). I suspect your action is throwing an error or there's a rejected Promise and any code after the `await dispatch` is not reachable.

Comment: Any chance @Coner you found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several ways to approach this. I usually do this by promises. Here's brief solution:

sendEmail function should return promise and then your code will work fine.

```
// You need to return promise by sendEmail function 

const sendEmail = () => dispatch => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        // Call your API here

        if(API_SUCCESS){
            resolve();
        }else{
            reject();
        }
        
    })
}
```

Now, following code will work as you did expect:

```
const handleEmailsent = async() => {
 await dispatch(sendEmail(email)); //if removed, navigate works. 
navigate("/login"); //does not navigate with the previous line.

};
```

Answer (score -1):

`await dispatch()` doesn't make any sense because `dispatch` function is **not** asynchronous. But internally, redux **asynchronously** updates the value to the updated value as soon as the action is dispatched. You can read about the entire working of redux in its official docs.

Coming to your code, since you want to navigate **only** after your redux store has the updated value, you need to employ an `useEffect` hook.

An example would be:

```js
const { value } = useSelector((store) => store.reducer);

useEffect(() => {
  if (value) {
     navigate("/any-route");
  }
}, [value]);

const someFunction = () => {
   dispatch(yourAction("new value"));
};
```

What this does different is

- it dispatches your action
- redux asynchronously updates the store to the value you specified
- the `useEffect` hook listens for store changes (the value you are fetching using `useSelector`)
- as soon as the value changes, the `useEffect` callback function is executed
- It checks if the value is present

  - If yes, then navigates to a route you specify.

The key thing to note here is that, the `dispatch` function is itself not an asynchronous function but it internally makes redux update its store to the latest value asynchronously. Therefore, a simple `await` keyword won't make the program execution wait until the value is actually updated in the store.

So, the dispatch is actually happening but your code isn't waiting for redux to reflect it in the store. By the time it even tells redux to update it, it navigates away to a new route therefore redux doesn't even have a chance to update it in the store.

Comment: I think you have some Redux concepts a bit mixed up. Dispatched actions ***can*** be asynchronous and awaited, e.g. Thunks, and the Redux store is always ***synchronously*** updated, e.g. reducer functions are 100% completely synchronous functions.